# Html list not updating from SQL database

Tags: javascript, html, sql, angularjs, cordova

I'm having an issue where a list on HTML isn't pulling all the information I want.
The information the list is grabbed from is a SQL database.
I've recently added a 6th item but it only shows 5 items and I'm not sure what to do to get the 6th item to appear. The pull should be from data.static.requestType.
I'm not super familiar with web development so bear with me as I try to figure this out.

**html**

```
<label>Request Type</label>
<select id="typeSel" name="typeSel" ng-model="requestType" ng-change="propertyLookupUpdate()" ng-options="i.id as (i.requestType) for i in data.static.requestType">
     <option value="">Select...</option>
</select>
```

**js**

```
angular.forEach($rootScope.data.rawData.startup.RelLocationAirportServiceType, function (locationAirportServiceTypeItem, locationAirportServiceTypeKey) {
                        if (utilities.validCheck(locationAirportServiceTypeItem, "object", true)) {
                            if (utilities.validCheck(locationAirportServiceTypeItem.tbRefLocation, "object", true) && locationAirportServiceTypeItem.tbRefLocation.active) {
                                $rootScope.data.rawData.startup.RelLocationAirportServiceType[locationAirportServiceTypeKey].tbRefLocation = utilities.convertDatestringRecursive(locationAirportServiceTypeItem.tbRefLocation);
                                $rootScope.data.static.location[locationAirportServiceTypeItem.tbRefLocation.id] = {};
                                $rootScope.data.static.location[locationAirportServiceTypeItem.tbRefLocation.id] = locationAirportServiceTypeItem.tbRefLocation;
                            }}});
```

Any idea?
Thanks.

Comment: Try `for i of` instead of `for i in`.

Comment: Thanks for the response, unfortunately that caused the list to be blank.